# Plot Totcounter-Value

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, counters, totcount

I'm trying to get tikzpicture and pgfplots working with totcount to create the following bars.

[image: Example from Word]

I count all occurrences of the different ratings with `\totcounter` and in text I am able to read the counts with:

```latex
\total{critCounter}
\total{highCounter}
\total{mediumCounter}
\total{lowCounter}
\total{infoCounter}
```

But when I try to load the values into a plot, I get a plethora of error messages.

```latex
\addplot[style={black,fill=red,mark=none}]
        coordinates {(Kritisch,\total{highCount})};
```

The messages reach from `Missing number, treated as zero.` to `Missing \endcsname inserted.` and `Undefined control sequence.`

I guess this burns down to compilation sequence issues. Does anyone have  an idea for a better approach?
The graph should show the identified issue ratings through the document, which I just count and want to visualize.

Comment: Try to use `(Kritisch,\thehighCount)` instead of `(Kritisch,\total{highCount})`.(because you did not provide a MWE - for the next time please add one - i assumed you defined your counters with `\newcounter{...}`)

Comment: Thanks, thehighCount would not work as the Graph is before the findings. However, I found another counter that is compatible with pgfplot, which is part of the `xassoccnt` package:
`\NewTotalDocumentCounter{lowCounter}`
`\stepcounter{lowCounter}%`
Calling it is possible with: `\TotalValue{lowCounter}`

Comment: I guess you need `\the\totvalue{highCount}`

Answer (score 0):

I should answer myself here.

The `totcounter` package is incompatible with `pgfplot` and I solved the issue by using `xassoccnt`.

Define the counter: `\NewTotalDocumentCounter{countername}`
Step like any other counter: `\stepcounter{countername}`
Read the counter: `\TotalValue{countername}`